# Database connection error with Postgres & Movable Type

Tags: perl, postgresql, ssl, movabletype, mt4

I'm trying to set up MovableType 4.34 using a Postgres database, and I'm getting the following (unhelpful) error message:

```
Connection error: authentication method 7 not supported
```

The database server doesn't support SSL connections, so I *suspect* that's to blame -- but I can't be sure (what is "authentication method 7" ?), and at any rate it's not clear to me how to see if MT is trying to use SSL connections for the database or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you turn on SSL in postgresql.conf? Just check it using this query:

```
SHOW ssl;
```

You have to check pg_hba.conf as well, [hostssl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) needs a proper setting.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Postgres configuration, and the sysadmin in charge of the webserver is somewhat...unwilling to make security-related changes.

Comment: @Doches: Enabling SSL would be tightening security, not loosening it.